# Ubuntu 12.04 disable release notification of 14.04 in Update Manager

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, notification

Both my parents are still using Ubuntu 12.04 and we don't intent to upgrade to 14.04 in the near future.

Is it possible to disable the upgrade notification in Update Manager? 
This because it's just confusing for them.

[image: Update Manager]

Answer (score 5):

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set:

```
Prompt=never
```

In the `[DEFAULT]` section (Use `sudo` with your favourite editor).
And never run `update-manager` with `-d`. That checks for the next development release available and overrides the above setting.

Answer (score 0):

Muru's answer was a good start but didn't work for me.  I additionally had to

In Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available
```

In Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

Then **reboot** and login.

(I don't know when the file location changed between 12.04 and 14.04 as I normally only use the LTS releases.)